# How to restrict browser to display complete page data at once using JQuery/Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a JSP page which contains three sections header,body and footer. I am loading header and footer sections with jsp's at runtime using JQuery syntax and body section contains some images/data displayed.

Now the problem I am facing is that, while running the application in browser, header page contains so many images which are being triggered from some locations due to that when ever I open this page in browser, first body section is getting diaplyed and then header content in being loaded. This is not I expect as I want all the page display at once.

I want to display all the sections at one time. Is there any way to tell browser to display content at once using Javascript/JQuery. I tried using `document.ready` in JQuery as well as `window.load` in javascript. None of them are working.

I am loading header/footer jsp's as below:

```
jQuery("#header").load('header.jsp');
jQuery("#footer").load('footer.jsp');
```

**Problem: How to make sure browser displays all the page at once instead of displaying each section slowly.**
To put simple, I feel browser works loading web page in top-bottom approach. So when the browser sees tag to load header.jsp it should load header page first and them move on to body followed by footer.But in my case it is loading body first as it is having less content and then slowly loading header.

PLease let me know if you need any further more details and provide me with any solution for this issue.

Comment: Google "Pre-loading images in html"

Comment: Use an overlay div which you remove on window.load.

Comment: Added problem statement in bit detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace the urls to whatever the url to your header and footer are):

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "url to header.jsp",
    success : function(response) {
           var headerHtml = response;
           getFooter(headerHtml );
    },
    error : function(e) {
    }
});

function getFooter(headerHtml){
    $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "url to footer.jsp",
    success : function(response) {
                $("#header").html(headerHtml);
                $("#footer").html(response);
        },
    error : function(e) {

    }
   });
}
```